# Why using operator OR (logical operator) in if-else, why not using AND (logcial operator) in if-else

Tags: c

I made the alphabet with the appearance of using stars to form the alphabet, but I was confused as to why to use the OR operation instead of the AND operation on if-else?

```
int row,column;
for(row=1;row<=4;row++){
    for(column=1;column<=7;column++){
        if((column==1 || column==2 || column==3 || column==5 || column==6 || column==7) && (row==1))
            printf(" ");
        else if((column==1 || column==2 || column==4 || column==6 || column==7) && (row==2))
            printf(" ");
        else if((column==1 || column==7) && (row==3))
            printf(" ");
        else if((column==2 || column==3 || column==4 || column==5 || column==6) && (row==4))
            printf(" ");
        else
            printf("*");
    } printf("\n");
}
```

Why using operator || in if-else? why not using operator && in if-else for condition column...

Comment: Wait. You wrote this code, but you're asking why it was written this way?

Comment: Test the row number before the column number because it is a simpler test.  You might even be able to measure the difference, though it is probably dwarfed by the cost of the I/O.

Comment: You can always rewrite an OR-expression as an AND-expression by negating each term as well as the result, and vice-versa.  Can also apply distributive laws.

Answer (score 1):

- `column==1 || column==2` will be true when `column` is `1` OR when `column` is `2`
- `column==1 && column==2` will be true when `column` is `1` AND when `column` is `2`. That can never happen as a variable cannot be `1` and `2` at the same time, so this condition will always be false.